# Is there a way to get CurrentDate and auto calculate EndDate of a Subscription in ASP.NET using SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In my project, the main motive is selling of memberships, and for that I want to insert current date and ending date into a SQL Server database from an ASP.NET web page when a user clicks "buy" button, the ending date needs to be 1 year after current date.

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE order_table
(
    order_id nvarchar(20) primary key,
    email nvarchar(60),
    issue_date date,
    end_date date
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DATEADD` function of SQL Server. an example is below.

```
SELECT GETDATE() --Get the current date

SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE()) --Get the date after one year
```

Comment: Can i use DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE()) like this - INSERT INTO order_table (email, issue_date, end_date) VALUES ('abc@email.com', GETDATE(), DATEADD(YEAR, 1, GETDATE()) );

Comment: yes, of course, you can use